# How to get the "navigation label" of the menu Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**What I am trying to do is:**

when the menu item is clicked, getting "navigation label" of corresponding menu item.

For example:

Top menu:
Shop | Pizza | Cake | Tea

The "navigation label" of each item is Shop, Pizza, Cake, Tea.

When the "Shop" item is clicked, then get the value of navigation label "Shop".

Is that would be possible?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use javascript for this, In jQuery:

```
$('.menu li').click(function(){
   var label = $(this).text();
   alert(label);
});
```

Comment: Ok, can explain the issue a bit clearer, if possible. What do you mean by 'Get the value of the label'?